# opening a new window without javascript or a href

Tags: javascript, web, window

I have a question, and I know it's a little wired.
Currently, i'm developing a website, and I wish to add some publicities.
So for my needs, I want that a new window opens, when the user opens my website.
I did it using javascript, but the problem is that JS is disabled by many users, so here I have to find a solution without using JS.
I made a lot of searches, but I couldn't find anything.
Can anyone help me?
Thanks a lot 
Best Regards

Comment: I don't think that JS is disabled by so many people, but that your JS triggers the popup-blocker of the browsers. What you are asking for is considered a bad practice. If you want to advertise sth. do it in your Tab; maybe you want to show a modal window?

Comment: that's what i must make, bcz JS is disabled, and i can't change anything for this point.
As I said in the description, I prefer to open a new window, without using JS, that must be done automatically without any click from the user.
Thanks

Comment: And I've tried to explain to you, that if a page opens a new window without User-interaction within the last 50ms or so, the Browser will consider this a illegitimate action and therefore block it; that is called the popup-blocker, nowadays implemented in any browser.

Comment: I don't know any legitimate way to accomplish your request. I was trying to show you alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35549197/opening-a-new-window-without-javascript-or-a-href/35549367#35549367" />
```

Comment: sry, it redirects the current window, but i wish to open a new one

Comment: There is another way, dont allow to use your application if they disable javascript . but i think most of the user where never disable javascript.May be i think they where using any ad blockers